How to calculate required force needed to compress paper waste for a waste baler?
I just wish to understand an approach to designing the necessary amount of compression force needed for a waste baler

It will depend on how compressed your starting material might be. For example if you compress something at a force, applying that amount of force is unlikely to compress it further.  On top of that, when you release the force, it will expand again.

Can you add specify the type of baler you are interested in? Also the waste type would help.
